# display database info on next page after loggin in using session

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and I'm going to try to explain it the way I could :D. I'm trying to accomplish when the user logged in (using username and password), it opens a new page with the users name, address etc.

In my database table, I have a username, password, name and address.

I was able to accomplish the login page using session but would like to how to get/fetch those information like name and address to the new page it opens.

Thank you,

MD :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [how-to-ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Espc. show us what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

correct me if i'm wrong.

Here is how u fetch the information from a certain table by using PHP and MySQL(PhpMyAdmin) database.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hotel");     //Connecting to the database
                                           

if($conn){
    $sql = "SELECT USER_NAME, USER_PASS FROM USER";     //SELECT statement
    $result = $conn->query($sql);                       //Executing the statement
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){                      //If query success
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){           //While loop to retrieve all data
            $user = $row["USER_NAME"];               //Assign Column USER_NAME in database to $user
            $pass = $row["USER_PASS"];               //Assign Column USER_PASS in database to $pass

            echo $user."</br>".$pass."</br>";        //Displaying the content
        }
    }else{
        echo "Query failed";
    }
}else{
    die("Fatal Error");
}

$conn->close();                                      //Close the database connection
```